# How spring works based on namespaces?

Tags: java, spring

I normally see spring modules are loaded based on namespace which is not clear to me though i have some vague understanding.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
```

>

**How spring internally uses namespace declared above like context,p, etc ?**

Here is my understanding :-

1. spring internally parses the xml.
2. While parsing ,it tries to find out the expected jars for all
   xsds (it internally knows jars names against schemaLocation values )
3. Spring processor validates and process the elements  based on
   namespaces(like context,p ) where context,p etc are default
   namespaces in one of the xsds found under step 2

**Is it correct ?**

Comment: Keep in mind that the actual namespace names used in tags are irrelevant. They're just a shorthand key to the XSD definition associated with them.

Comment: @chrylis can you elaborate "  Keep in mind that the actual namespace names used in tags are irrelevant " ?

Comment: It's irrelevant whether you use `context` or `c` or `foobar`. The only thing that matters is that the namespace name (`context`, for example) matches the key in the list of namespace URIs.

Comment: @chrylis can you elaborate your last comments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct, while loading context Spring parses the xml and verifies all the namespaces. And all the definations for these namespaces are inside jars, which you provide through maven or in build path, for example, namespace defination for xmlns:context is found in spring-context.jar.

spring-context.jar contains the spring-context-3.0.xsd, same you can see at **spring-context.jar/META-INF/spring.schema**.

And once namespaces are verified it validates and process the elements based on namespaces as you mentioned.